# viewContentLoaded equivalent in Angular 4

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, pageload

New to Angular 4 and ionic3. We need to call a function on every view change. Is there any common place where we can place this function call like in angular 1 we can use viewContentLoaded event?

In our scenario, all the navigations are happening via ionic, and after some research found that we can implement ngAfterViewInit interface. But I believe we need to implement this in every page. Is there any common place where we can implement this interface so that function can be called on every page load or if this doesn’t help, please suggest on how this can be achieved.

Comment: On every view change?  Like when you route between 2 pages?

Comment: Yes. After the page load

Comment: why not put it in a service and then call the service on every page?

Answer (score 1):

in app.component.ts

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  const navigated$ = router.events.map(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd);

  navigated$.subscribe(// ... logic);
}
```